# My function is not returning the product I want, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, product

I am trying to return the product of every two numbers of a number, e.g. we have number 123, I am trying to have 1*2 and then 2*3. Whichever is largest, should be added to the final 'product; variable.

```
const findLargestProduct = array => {

    let i=0, j=1, product = 0;

    while (j < array.length) {

        let result = array[i] * array[j];

        if (result > product) {
            product = result;

        }
        i++
        j++

    } return product;

}

console.log(findLargestProduct(589))
```

the result for this code should be 72 (8*9=72)

Comment: `589` is not an array, it's a number.

Comment: Numbers don't have a `length` property!

Answer (score 0):

The function expected array. You should do this: findLargestProduct([5,8,9]).
Or in the function: `array = array.toString().split('')`

```js
const findLargestProduct = array => {
  let i = 0,
    j = 1,
    product = 0;

  while (j < array.length) {
    let result = array[i] * array[j];

    if (result > product) {
      product = result;
    }
    i++;
    j++;
  }
  return product;
};

console.log(findLargestProduct([5,8,9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you input 589 is a number so `array.length` is `undefined` and it did not go to while loop.

You can change from 589 to '589' it worked.

```js
const findLargestProduct = array => {

    let i=0, j=1, product = 0;
    console.log(array.length);
    while (j < array.length) {

        let result = array[i] * array[j];
        

        if (result > product) {
            product = result;

        }
        i++
        j++

    } return product;

}

console.log(findLargestProduct('589'))
```